# Why the value in TextFormField() remain , even if the previous page is popped with pushAndRemoveUntil()?

Tags: flutter

I learned `pushAndRemoveUntil()` would pop all pages so far.
However, please refer to the code and screenshot below. If user typed `dummy` dummy and moved on `ResetPassword()' with 'pushAndRemoveUntil()` and finally moved back to same page `LogIn()`, the value `dummy` still remains.

Please kindly why this happens, Does 'pushAndRemoveUntil()` not remove all previous page, or other factor effect this problem ?
and let me know how can I fix it as well.

```
//logIn.dart
final TextEditingController  loginIdController = TextEditingController();


class LogIn extends ConsumerWidget {
  final _formKeyName = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Focus(
      focusNode: focusNode, 
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: focusNode.requestFocus, 
        child: Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: Align(
                          child: Form(
                            key: formKey, //point
                            child: TextFormField(
                              maxLength: maxLength,
                              obscureText: obscureTextFunction(ref),
                              focusNode: textType == "birth" ? focusNodeBirth : null,
                              controller: loginIdController
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                errorMaxLines: 5,
                                counterText: "",
                                labelText: "Email-Adress", //**
                                hintText: "Email-Adress", //**
                                isDense: true,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              ref.read(completeErrorMessage.notifier).update((state)=>null);
                              // generalNavigator(context: context, destination: ResetPassword(), goBack: "go");
                              removeNavigator(context: context, destination: ResetPassword());
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              "Forget Password?",
                              style: MyText(
                                      myWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                      myFontSize: 11,
                                      myColor: MyStyle.mainColor)
                                  .style(),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ]
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
//reset.dart
class ResetPassword extends ConsumerWidget {
  final _formKeyReset = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final alertMessage = ref.watch(completeErrorMessage);
    final focusNode =
        FocusNode(); https://www.kamo-it.org/blog/textfield-focus/

    return Focus(
      focusNode: focusNode, //A
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: focusNode.requestFocus,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
              child: Stack(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Align(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          for (var i = 0; i < [_formKeyReset].length; i++) {
                            if (!([_formKeyReset][i]
                                .currentState!
                                .validate())) {
                              return;
                            }
                          }
                          resetPass(ref, resetPassController.text);
                        },
                        child: const Text("Reset the password"),
                        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0))),
                          foregroundColor: MyStyle.mainColor,
                          side: const BorderSide(
                            color: MyStyle.mainColor,
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        ref.read(completeErrorMessage.notifier).update((state) => null);
                        removeNavigator(context: context, destination: LogIn());
                      },
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Text(
                          "Go Back to LogIn",
                          style: MyText(
                                  myWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                  myFontSize: 12,
                                  myColor: MyStyle.mainColor)
                              .style(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving it is pretty easy just add a `loginIdController.clear()` function before navigating to the next screen :

```
                  Align(
                        ...
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {

                                  loginIdController.clear(); //add this
                                  ref.read(completeErrorMessage.notifier).update((state)=>null);
                                  // generalNavigator(context: context, destination: ResetPassword(), goBack: "go");
                                  removeNavigator(context: context, destination: ResetPassword());
                                },
                                ...
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

Comment: also on pop you can clear data using controller clear mothds.

Comment: Yeah sure just call the `textEditingController.clear()` method before the pop method in any onPress/onTap and you'll be good to go.

Comment: @RisheekMittal thanks for your helpful advise and it works.
By the way, just for my basic understanding, Is it because the problem of  `textEditingController` that the value remains even if all pages were popped by `pushAndRemoveUntil()` ?

Comment: In other words what is the `pop' actually mean ? cause the value in text field remains. I just thought once the pages are popped and moved to the pages again, all widgets are rebuild and naturally the value typed before is cleared by the pop.

Comment: See when you're popping to a previous page in flutter it keeps the state as it was earlier i.e all the fields and all the changes you made are kept exactly as they were before as all the pages are kept in a Stack. btw can you upvote and mark it as an answer if you're satisfied.